# I am trying to compare sport_id in user table but sport_id are store in array how can i compare with php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

sports table:

```
id   name
1    Athletics
2    Aerobics
```

users table:

```
id  sports_type 
1     1,2        
2     1
```

Model query:

```
function select_sports($sports) 
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->like('name', $sports); 
    $query = $this->db->get('sports');
    //print_r($query);exit();
    return $query->row();
} 

function get_filterde_user() 
{ 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
 $sports = $this->input->post('sports');
 $query = $this->user_model->select_sports($sports);
 $sport_id = $query->id; 
 $sport_get = explode(',',$sport_id);
 $query = $this->user_model->get_filterde_user(); 
 $arr = array(); 
 foreach ($query as $row=>$value) {
     if ($value->sports_type != 0 && $value->user_type != 1) { 
         $sports_type = explode(',', $value->sports_type);
         foreach ($sport_get as $search) { 
             if (in_array($search, $sports_type)) {
                 echo  $arr[$row]['name'] = $value->user_name; die; 
             }  
         } 
     } 
 }
```

but it's not give all field related sports_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your database structure it seems that it quit difficult but poosible,
i recommend the database strucure as below:

1. sports table:

   id sport_name
2. users table:

   id user_name user_adress
3. user_sports:

   id users_id(users table pk) sports_id(sport table pk)

and then try searching operation, it will be very easy

Comment: okay thanx.. can you help me how to write query with your sugested database structure.

Comment: you have sports name array right..
from sports array select sports id

Comment: @yash then use this code 

    $this->db->select('users_id'); 
    $result=$this->db->where_in('sports_id',$sports_ids); //$sports_ids    is array selected from sports table 
 $result = $result->result_array(); 
    From $result create $users_ids array
    And finaly from $users_ids array
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where_in('user_id',$user_ids);
    $required_result=$this->db->get('users');
    Then ,
    $required_result =  $required_result->result_array();
    This is requird output